# AS3 Multiple Application Domain using local null.swf file

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder, flashdevelop

I have the following issue, I cannot find a solution on the web, please let me know if you can help me or point me to a proper info about this issue.

To understand the background, Im porting a game from flashDevelop to Flash Builder  (please dont give me tips about this comment if doesn't help to my particular problem). Everything works fine right now, the game use a file null.swf as a container of local files (I don't undertand that part completely, but the game has a lot of embed swc files, and the game use the null.swf to access those files, through LoaderMax).

The problem is that everything works fine with a fast build, but it's not working with a standard build, I have the error on Loader class that says "Multiple application domains are not supported on this operating system".

Useful information:

- Im using AIR 3.9, compilation flash swf-version=20 (I had 18 when I started with this issue)
- null.swf is properly included on the IPA, the code recognize the file, and as I said before it works with a fast build.
- For embed swc files, I had to include the files with a compiler argument: "-include-libraries ../../filename.swc ../../filename2.swc etc.."

Thanks for any help.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed, using a context:

context = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain, null);

If I use the third parameter, like ..., SecurityDomain.currentDomain);  it doesn't work.